# Order of evaluation in Python is not clear

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment, operator-precedence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple assignment in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-in-python)

As we have learnt right since we started with C that on a computer while working in one thread, all operations occur one by one.

I have a doubt in Python 3 language. I have seen codes for swapping variable values using the expression:

```
a,b = b,a
```

Or for Fibonacci series using:

```
a,b = b,a+b
```

How can these work ? But they do work :O

Does the Python system internally create some temporary variable for these ? What's the order of assignment so that both effectively give the correct result ?

Regards,
Nikhil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a high level, you are creating two tuples, the left hand side and right hand side, and assigning the right one to the left, which changes the variables one by one to their opposites. Python is a higher level language, so there are more abstractions like this when compared to a language like C.

At a low level, you can see quite clearly what is happening by using the `dis` module, which can show you the python bytecode for a function:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def test(x, y):
...     x, y = y, x
... 
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 ROT_TWO             
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

What happens is it uses `ROT_TWO` to swap the order of the items on the stack, which is a very efficient way of doing this.

Comment: One thing to be careful here: as this answer states in the beggining, we have to think of Python first creating a tuple (thus, yes, as the O.P. puts, "some temporary variable for these" is created on the form of the tuple object. After the right habd side is processed, its values are assigned in sequence to the names on the left hand side.  The surprise on the bytecode shown, is that a 2 tuple creation is skipped alltogether on this special case - we have to keep in mind it is a compiler optimization.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `a, b`, you create `tuple`.

```
>>> 1, 2
(1, 2)
```

So, nothing special in evaluation order.

Answer (score 0):

From the Fibonacci example with `a=1` and `b=1`. First, the right hand side is evaluated: `b,a+b` resulting in the tuple `(1,2)`. Next, the right hand side is assigned to the left hand side, namely `a` and `b`. So yes, the evaluation on the right is stored in memory, and then `a` and `b` changed to point to these new values.