# Swaping values in Pythonic way leads to wrong answers

Tags: python

Question: [Swap Two Nodes in Linked List](http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/swap-two-nodes-in-linked-list/)

Answer 1:

```
def swapNodes(self, head, v1, v2):
        dummyHead = ListNode(-1, head)
        pre_v1 = None
        pre_v2 = None
        curNode = dummyHead
        while curNode.next:
            if curNode.next.val == v1:
                pre_v1 = curNode
            elif curNode.next.val == v2:
                pre_v2 = curNode

            if pre_v1 and pre_v2:

                pre_v1.next, pre_v2.next, pre_v1.next.next, pre_v2.next.next = \
                pre_v2.next, pre_v1.next, pre_v2.next.next, pre_v1.next.next
                break

            curNode = curNode.next
        return dummyHead.next
```

This answer lead to a wrong answer when the input is 1->2->3->4->null. The output should be 1->4->3->2->null. But it returns 1->4->null

If I change

```
pre_v1.next, pre_v2.next, pre_v1.next.next, pre_v2.next.next = \
pre_v2.next, pre_v1.next, pre_v2.next.next, pre_v1.next.next
```

to

```
pre_v1.next, pre_v2.next = pre_v2.next, pre_v1.next
pre_v1.next.next, pre_v2.next.next = pre_v2.next.next, pre_v1.next.next
```

The answer is correct.

Do I miss something? Is there any "trap" that I have to be careful about when swapping values in this way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple assignment and evaluation order in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python)

Comment: As Moinuddin said, the first one evaluates in a different order: The order is important: the order you swap `pre_v1.next` & `pre_v1.next.next` will affect the outcome

Answer (score 0):

The thing you have to understand with using the tuple-unpacking trick to swap values in Python is that they essentially all happen in parallel, not sequentially. In your first example, for instance, `pre_v1.next.next` takes on the value of `pre_v2.next_next`, but in the same expression you also change `pre_v1.next`, so once the whole thing is done evaluating, `pre_v1.next.next` won't point where you think it does because you're now essentially evaluating `(pre_v2.next).next`, which has also been changed.