# Swapping items in container - evaluation order

Tags: python, evaluation

Edited for clarity:

Why do the list items not swap?

```
# python 3.5
lst = [0, 1]
lookup = {0: 1, 1: 0}

lst[0], lst[lookup[lst[0]]] = lst[lookup[lst[0]]], lst[0]
# lst is still unchanged; why aren't items 0 and 1 not swapped
```

Comment: This runs fine in Python 3.5. What's the problem?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis  Sorry, rewrote for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rhs is evaluated before the lhs. That's not the problem.

The problem is how the lhs is evaluated. You can prove this to yourself by running this statement:

```
lst[0], lst[lookup[lst[0]]] = 1, 0
```

Note that the assigning to `lst[0]` occurs *before* the evaluation of `lst[lookup[lst[0]]]`. So the `lst[0]` in that complex expression is the *new* value, not the old value.

Breaking it down:

```
lst[0], lst[lookup[lst[0]]] = 1, 0
=> lst[0] = 1; lst[lookup[lst[0]]] = 0
=> lst[0] = 1; lst[lookup[1]] = 0
=> lst[0] = 1; lst[0] = 0
```

So the final result appears unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Because:

```
lst[0], lst[lookup[lst[0]]] = lst[lookup[lst[0]]], lst[0]
```

is equivalent to:

```
lst[0]= lst[lookup[lst[0]]]
lst[lookup[lst[0]]] = lst[0]
```