# python fibonacci - what is the difference?

Tags: python, fibonacci

I am learning python and I have some question:

What is the difference between

```
a,b = 0,1
for x in range(100):
    print(a)
    a=b
    b=a+b
```

and

```
a,b = 0,1
for x in range(100):
    print(a)
    a,b = b, a+b
```

First one gives bad result, but why?

Comment: This is good to go through with pen and paper. Write down the values of the variables, then update them step by step.

Comment: In the first example you assign a new value to A before assigning a value to B. In the second case you do it simultaneously.

Comment: Because `a` has changed and thus `a + b` will be different. Assignment calculates the results of the right hand side before applying the results to the left.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8725769/5033247

Answer (score 1):

Because you first set `a = b`, your new `b` will have the value of twice the old `b`. You overwrite `a` to early. A correct implementation should use a temporary variable `t`:

```
a,b = 0,1
for x in range(100):
print(a)
    t=a
    a=b
    b=t+b
```

This is basically what you do by using sequence assignment.

In your original code you have:

```
a,b = 0,1
for x in range(100):
    print(a)
    a=b # a now is the old b
    b=a+b # b is now twice the old a so b'=2*b instead of b'=a+b
```

So this would result in jumping by multiplying with two each time (after first loading in `1` into `a` the first step).

---

An equivalent problem is the swap of variables. If you want `a` to take the value of `b` and vice versa, you **cannot** write:

```
#wrong swap
a = b
b = a
```

Because you lose the value of `a` after the first assignment. You can use a temporary `t`:

```
t = a
a = b
b = t
```

or use sequence assignment in Python:

```
a,b = b,a
```

where a tuple `t = (b,a)` is first created, and then assigned to `a,b`.

Comment: You on Windows or Linux?

Comment: @MYGz: Linux of course, why?

Comment: Why do you write `<code><pre>` There is a chrome extension called text area formatter, You can select the code part and indent it with tab.

Comment: @MYGz: well usually it is as fast as writing code itself (the formatting part) when using an advantage kinesis :) Every swap between keyboard and mouse is a waste of time.

Comment: Are you telling me select code and press a tab can sometimes be slower for you than writing `<pre><code></code></pre>`. I can never reach those typing speeds :D

Comment: @MYGz: a kinesis is a keyboard where each key and almost each key combination can be programmed to emit a sequence of keystrokes.

Comment: Oh I see didn't knew about it. Can you share a link for more info? Is it a keyboard or software?

Comment: https://www.kinesis-ergo.com/shop/advantage-for-pc-mac/