# Reversing a LinkedList in python

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class node:
    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = node()
```

This is how I initialize my LinkedList data structure in python.

After I append some nodes, by doing

```
my_list.append(1)
my_list.append(2)
my_list.append(3)
my_list.append(4)
```

and display it using the function that I wrote,

```
def display(self):

    elems = []
    curr = self.head

    while curr.next != None:
        curr = curr.next
        elems.append(curr.data)

    print(elems)
```

It prints out `[1, 2, 3, 4]` which seems fine.

However, when I try to reverse it by using the function below

```
def reverseList(self):

    curr = self.head
    prev = None


    while curr != None:

        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = curr.next

    self.head = prev
```

It gives me an empty linkedList `[]`. If I draw the LinkedList on a paper, it seems fine and I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You'll need a third variable to keep track of the "next" node. curr.next is not a sufficient reference to this node since you're redefining the node's next pointer in the first line of the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reverse

Look at the order of your operations:

```
curr.next = prev
prev = curr
curr = curr.next
```

Before you do `curr = curr.next`, `curr.next` is equal to `prev`, which is equal to None (during the first, and final iteration).

You need to store the value of `curr.next` in an intermediate variable before changing it.

Alternatively, you can use Python's multiple assignment ([Multiple assignment and evaluation order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python)) to assign all variables at once after evaluating their values:

```
curr.next, prev, curr = prev, curr, curr.next
```

### Display

You have the same kind of problem in the display function.

```
while curr.next != None:
    curr = curr.next
    elems.append(curr.data)
```

You don't append the first `curr.data`, you directly change `curr` into `curr.next`.

Comment: After I make a change, I get `[3, 2, 1, None]` instead of `[4, 3, 2,1 ]` and I am not sure why the 4 is gone. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @bazzells, you need a third variable to keep track of the next node before discarding it:

```
def reverse(self):
    curr = self.head
    prev = None
    while curr is not None:
        next_ = curr.next
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = next_
    self.head = prev
```

Note on code style:

- use `is None` or `is not None` to compare an instance with `Nome` because you only need to compare identity (memory address).
- class names should be in CamelCase,
- variable and function names should be in snake_case.
- avoid using `next` in your code because it’s a built-in function and can also be confusing (replace by `next_node`, for instance).

Comment: After I make a change, I get [3, 2, 1, None] instead of [4, 3, 2,1 ] and I am not sure why the 4 is gone. Any idea?