# Python swap leads to unexpected results when order changes

Tags: python, swap, object-reference

Python supports 1-line A/B swap (A , B = B , A), and we would expect (B, A = A, B) would lead to the same result.  However, I met a strange behavior when dealing with a list entry.  I simplify my finding in the code below:

```
nums = [0, 0, 0, 0]
n = 2
print(nums, "expected case")
nums[n - 1], n = n, nums[n - 1]
print(n, nums)

nums = [0, 0, 0, 0]
n = 2
print(nums, "unexpected case")
n, nums[n - 1] = nums[n - 1], n
print(n, nums)
```

Below are output from executing the program above:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0] expected case
0 [0, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0] unexpected case
0 [0, 0, 0, 2]
```

Question: why the order change above leads to different result?  It appears that in the unexpected case, n gets assigned to 0 first, before nums[-1] gets updated.

Comment: `nums[n - 1]` *means something different* if `n` has been assigned already.  Assignment targets are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: I have learned a lot about Python's swap semantics from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950432/1804173).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption (that `A, B = B, A` and `B, A = A, B` are equivalent statement) is only true if `A` and `B` do not depend on each other. The problem is that in both cases, the right expression is what you expect it to be, but not the left one. In one case, `n` is assigned (to 0) before `nums[n-1]`, so you actually access the `0-1=-1`-nth case of the list (which is the last one, as shown by the example). In the other case, `n-1` is computed *before* `n` is assigned again, so `nums[n-1]` corresponds to `nums[1]`. Keep in mind that expression are "evaluated" from left to right, even when assigning.

Comment: This was my assumption based on sample output, thank your for detailed explanation.