# Strange Effect of Python Assignment?

Tags: python, syntax, programming-languages

As we all know, for Python, we could easily assignment multiple variables in one line. But here I encounter a strange situation. Say we have a list:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And then, we do

```
x[0], x[x[0]] = 2, 1
```

Finally, we would get

```
x = [2, 2, 3, 4]
```

instead of

```
x = [2, 1, 3, 4]
```

Could anyone explain what is going wrong here? How would python implement the multiple variables assignment in one line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python

Comment: So basically, Python will evaluate right-hand side of the statement (only read, no contention), and then it will assign to variables on the left-hand side from left to right. Thanks all!!

Answer (score 1):

The resulting list is not `[2, 2, 3, 4]`, it's `[2, 2, 1, 4]`. `x[0]` is assigned the value `2`, then `x[x[0]]` becomes `x[2]` and is assigned the value `1`

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is, python first executes your first instruction . `x[0]= 2`

So after 1st execution, `x=[2,2,3,4]`

Then it executes the 2nd one. So it changes the value of `x[2]`

after 2nd execution, `x=[2,2,1,4]`

and gives the result as `[2, 2, 1, 4]`