# What is the code below the fourth line how do you do in a A p of a plus a B?

Tags: python

How does the fourth line in the code below work?

```
a, b = 0, 1
while b < 10:
   print b
   a, b = b, a + b
```

I don't have a problem, I just don't know how it's working.

Comment: It is a case of swap, specifically a tuple swap. It assigns to `a` the value of `b` and to `b` the sum of `a+b`. For further information, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python).

Comment: The code specifies that initially `a=0` and `b=1`, in while loop, print the value of `b`, `a=b` (value of `b` is copied into `a`), `b=a+b` (sum of `a` and `b` is copied into `b`) until `b` is lesser than or equal to 9. Output would be: `1 1 2 3 5 8`, forming a fibonacci series

Comment: @Preetkaran Singh. Fibonacci sequence, not series.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to explain this line (formatted for readability): 
`a, b = b, a + b`.

Essentially you are assigning a tuple to another tuple, and when you do that in python you 'unpack' one tuple into the other. You can read about it [here](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/).

In your specific case, firstly the tuple `(b, a + b)` is evaluated and then it is assigned to the tuple `(a, b)`. For example in the first iteration of the loop `a = 0` and `b = 1`, so `(b, a + b) = (1, 1)`. Therefore the last line will be equivalent to `(a, b) = (1, 1)`.

You can read more in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python).