# very strange behavior when swap two elements in the list in python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, swap

I have a list

```
a = [-1,4,3,1]
```

we have

```
a[1] = 4
a[3] = 1
```

now I want to swap `a[1]` and `a[3]`

The following code work very well:

```
a[1], a[3]  = a[3], a[1]
```

But If I use:

```
a[1], a[a[1]-1] = a[a[1]-1], a[1]
```

It gives me:

```
 a = [4,1,3,1]
```

The answer is not correct. What happen here since we know `a[1] - 1 = 3`. Any thought, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fundamentally the same question as [Multiple assignment and evaluation order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python) with a superficial wrinkle because of the convoluted indexing.

The things to bear in mind here:

- The right side is evaluated completely before the left side is evaluated at all
- The tuple assignments are evaluated completely from left to right

The docs state this (albeit sparely) here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right. Notice that while evaluating an assignment, the right-hand side is evaluated before the left-hand side.

Here I illustrate these rules as applied to your situation:

`State of a      Evaluation of expression            Comment
[-1, 4, 3, 1]    a[1], a[a[1]-1] = a[a[1]-1], a[1]   <start>
[-1, 4, 3, 1]    a[1], a[a[1]-1] = a[4-1], a[1]      a[1] resolves to 4
[-1, 4, 3, 1]    a[1], a[a[1]-1] = a[3], a[1]        4-1 is 3
[-1, 4, 3, 1]    a[1], a[a[1]-1] = 1, a[1]           a[3] resolves to 1
[-1, 4, 3, 1]    a[1], a[a[1]-1] = 1, 4              a[1] resolves to 4
[-1, 1, 3, 1]    a[a[1]-1] = 4                       a[1] = 1 assigned
[-1, 1, 3, 1]    a[1-1] = 4                          a[1] resolves to 1
[-1, 1, 3, 1]    a[0] = 4                            1-1 is 0
[4, 1, 3, 1]                                         a[0] = 4 assigned`