# Splitting multiple assignment doesn't produce the same output

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Is this syntax:

```
x, y = 0,1

while y < 50:
    print(y)
    x, y = y, x+y
```

The same as this:

```
x = 0
y = 1

while y < 50:
    print(y)
    x = y
    y = x+y
```

If so why do they print different results?  I'm trying to understand how the first code prints: `1, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34` because when I debug in my head and run the second code it prints: `1, 2, 8, 16, 32`.  Basically I cannot understand how the first code is working line by line.

Comment: In the second, first you reassign `x` with the value of `y` and then assign `y` with `x + y`. In Python, the right hand of an operation is evaluated first. So `x, y = y, x + y` is first evaluated on the right side and then the assignments occur.

Comment: I guess this illustrates it better `x, y = 0, 1`, leads to `x = 0`, `y = 1`. Then `x, y = y, x + y` leads to `x, y = 1, 0 + 1`, that results in `x = 1` and `y = 1`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple assignment and evaluation order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They aren't the same.

In multiple assignments such as `x, y = y, x+y`, the right side is evaluated first. So `x+y` is evaluated, then `y` is set equal to `x+y`.

Say `x=0` and `y=1`. Then, `x, y = y, x+y` evaluates to `x, y = 1, 0+1`, so `x, y = 1, 1`. `y = 1`.

In the second example, `x = y` causes `x = 1`, and the next line `y = x+y` causes `y = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason they give different results is that in the first one, you modify x and y at the same time, however in the second code, first you increase x and then you modify y, which is unfavorable.

Answer (score 0):

The first code uses multiple assignment in Python, where you create a tuple and loop over it and assign values to each variable

This is how Python handles your line :

```
(x,y) = (y,x+y)
```

This code is correct : you can traverse and observe it,

```
x,y = 0,1
x,y = 1,1
x,y = 1,2
x,y = 2,3
x,y = 3,5
```

The second code is totally wrong :

```
x = y
y = x+y
```

Since x is initialized with y in the first line : 
the second line is consequently y = 2*y, hence your output keeps on doubling