# Python - Multiple Assignment

Tags: python, variable-assignment, multiple-assignment

Recently I was reading through the official Python documentation when I came across the example on how to code the Fibonacci series as follows:

```
a, b = 0, 1 
while a < 10:
 print (a)
 a, b = b, a + b
```

which outputs to `0,1,1,2,3,5,8`

Since I've never used *multiple assignment* myself, I decided to hop into Visual Studio to figure out how it worked. I noticed that if I changed the notation to...

```
a = 0
b = 1
while a < 10:
 print (a) 
 a, b = b, a + b
```

... the output remains the same.

However, if I change the notation to...

```
a = 0
b = 1
while a < 10:
 print(a)
 a = b
 b = a + b
```

... the output changes to `0, 1, 2, 4, 8`

The way I understand *multiple assignments* is that it shrinks what can be done into two lines into one. But obviously, this reasoning must be flawed if I can't apply this logic to the variables under the `print(a)` command.

It would be much appreciated if someone could explain why this is/what is wrong with my reasoning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple assignment and evaluation order in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
a = 0
b = 1
while a < 10:
 print(a)
 a = b
 b = a + b
```

In this case, `a` becomes `b` and then `b` becomes the **changed** `a` + `b`

```py
a, b = 0, 1 
while a < 10:
 print (a)
 a, b = b, a+b
```

In this case, `a` becomes `b` and at the same time `b` becomes the `original` a + b.

That's why, in your case `b` becomes the **new** `a + b`, which, since `a = b`, basically means `b = b + b`. That's why the value of `b` doubles everytime.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `a, b = d, e` the order in which assignment happens in from right to left. That is, b is first given the value of `e` and then the other assignment happens. So when you do `a, b = b, a + b` what you are effectively writing is,

```
 b = a + b
 a = b
```

Hence the difference.

You can verify this by doing

```
a = 0
b = 1
while a < 10:
 a, b = b, a + b
 print(a, b)
```

the first output is `1 1`. So first `b` becomes `0+1` and *then* a is given the value of `b=a` making it also `1`.

If you want more details on how this works, you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725673/multiple-assignment-and-evaluation-order-in-python) question.

Comment: `a, b = 1, 2` then `a, b = b, a + b` outputs `(2, 3)`. But when `a, b = 1, 2` then `b = a + b; a = b` outputs (3, 3). How are they the same?

Comment: I think this question is, in fact, a duplicate of the one you linked... but I also think you've misread the answer. Everything to the right of the `=` is evaluated first, and only *then* are the values assigned to the variables on the left. (And in fact, those assignments technically happen from left to right, though that rarely matters.)

Answer (score -1):

In a multiple assignment, the right side is always computed first.

In effect,

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

is the same as:

```
b = a + b
a = b
```

Comment: This isn't correct. As Vthechamp's answer says, each variable on the left is assigned to the *original* value of the variables on the right -- that is, their values *before* the assignment.