# Multiple assignments into a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to assign values to more than one keys of a dictionary in a more concise way than the one below?

I mean, let `d` be a dictionary initialized as below:

```
d={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}
```

To assign values to multiple keys I need to do this:

```
d['a']=10
d['b']=200
d['c']=30
```

Can I achieve same with something like this:

```
d['a','b','c']=10,200,30
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can use [dict.update](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
d.update({'a': 10, 'b': 200, 'c': 30})
```

This will overwrite the values for existing keys and add new key-value-pairs for keys that do not already exist.

Comment: You can also write this as `d.update(a=10, b=200, c=300)`, as long as the keys are valid identifiers (just like you can in the constructor).

Comment: There is a faster way: `d = {**d, **dict(zip(keys, values))}`. See my comment  for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45043651/618045

Comment: @Sklavit that is however highly unpythonic

Comment: @WiseStrawberry. Why? This is legal python syntax (Python >=3.5).

Comment: Not saying its not legal python syntax, its just not very readable, I think its elegant, but not readable. Just my 2 cents. In python readable code is in general prefered over complex code.

Comment: @abarnert definitely a cool alternate, but I am wary of its readability down the line (e.g., if 'a' is a key string, then calling it as a keyword that could be anything could generate confusion). Because of that I go with the syntax in the original accepted answer. That said, good to know this alternate exists I didn't know before!

Answer (score 15):

You can also simply use the [multiple assigment semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5182573/2291710):

```
d['a'], d['b'], d['c'] = 10, 200, 30
```

Comment: most elegant solution

Answer (score 10):

You can always wrap it in a function:

```
def multiassign(d, keys, values):
    d.update(zip(keys, values))
```

Even if you didn't know about `update`, you could write it like this:

```
def multiassign(d, keys, values):
    for k, v in zip(keys, values):
        d[k] = v
```

Or you can even write a `dict` subclass that gives you exactly the syntax you wanted:

```
class EasyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            return [super().__getitem__(k) for k in key]
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            self.update(zip(key, value))
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
    def __delitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, tuple):
            for k in key: super().__delitem__(k)
        else:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
```

Now:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'd': 4}
>>> multiassign(d, ['a', 'b', 'c'], [10, 200, 300])
>>> d
{'a': 10, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 4}
>>> d2 = EasyDict({'a': 1, 'd': 4})
>>> d2['a', 'b', 'c'] = 100, 200, 300
>>> d2
{'a': 10, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 4}
```

Just be aware that it will obviously no longer be possible to use tuples as keys in an `EasyDict`.

Also, if you were going to use this for something serious, you'd probably want to improve the error handling. (`d['a', 'b'] = 1` will give a cryptic message about `zip argument #2 must support iteration`, `d['a', 'b', 'c'] = 1, 2` will silently work and do nothing to `c`, etc.)

Answer (score 6):

A speed comparison, from the worst to the best:

```
Python 3.5.3 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 15 2017, 10:43:23) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import numpy.random as nprnd
   ...: d = dict([(_, nprnd.rand()) for _ in range(1000)])
   ...: values = nprnd.randint(1000, size=10000)
   ...: keys = nprnd.randint(1000, size=10000)
   ...: def multiassign(d, keys, values):
   ...:     for k, v in zip(keys, values):
   ...:         d[k] = v
   ...:
   ...: d1 = dict(d)
   ...: %timeit multiassign(d1, keys, values)
   ...: d1 = dict(d)
   ...: %timeit {**d1, **{keys[i]: values[i] for i in range(len(keys))}}
   ...: d1 = dict(d)
   ...: %timeit d1.update(zip(keys, values))
   ...: d1 = dict(d)
   ...: %timeit {*d1.items(), *zip(keys, values)}
   ...: d1 = dict(d)
   ...: %timeit {**d1, **{key: value for key, value in zip(keys, values)}}
   ...: d1 = dict(d)
   ...: %timeit {**d1, **dict(zip(keys, values))}
4 ms ± 25.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
3.66 ms ± 29.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
3.17 ms ± 31.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.81 ms ± 98.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.38 ms ± 75.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
1.96 ms ± 21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So the clear winner is recreation of dictionary from dictionaries.

Comment: Running the same test (on M1), I get different results:
934 µs ± 9.61 µs per loop;
1.3 ms ± 23.8 µs per loop; 
744 µs ± 1.3 µs per loop;
1.02 ms ± 2.17 µs per loop; 
816 µs ± 955 ns per loop; 
693 µs ± 1.51 µs per loop;

You can improve update's performance by instantiating a dict in advance; `d1.update(dict(zip(keys, values)))` has the same runtime as `{**d1, **dict)(zip(keys, values)}`

`{**d1, **d2}` would also be less effective relative to `update` in a situation where you are repeatedly updating the dict with new keys and thus making larger dicts. Here you only overwrite keys.

Comment: I suppose it depends on Python version. Which version did you use?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't record anything about these experiments beyond what's in my comment and I don't remember which environment I used. It might also have something to do with CPU architecture.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dictionary comprehension e.g.

```
letters, nos = ['a','b','c'], [1,2,3]
d = {letters[i]: nos[i] for i in range(len(nos))}
```

output:

> {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}

Comment: With data in that format, `dict(zip(letters, nos))` would be neater