# How to Create Instance Attributes By Lopping Over __init__ Arguments?

Tags: python, class, constructor, args, keyword-argument

I was wondering if there was a way to generate class attributes by looping over the arguments of the **init** method without explicitly referring to a list containing all the arguments of the **init** method?

In the example below could I loop over hp, image, speed, x, y to create the self arguments ?

```
class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, hp, image, speed, x, y):

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super(Character, self).__init__()

        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(x, y) #initial placement
        self.speed = speed
        self.hp = hp
```

For example with a loop that would look like that:

```
class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, hp, image, speed, x, y):

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super(Character, self).__init__()

        for arg in arguments:
             self.arg = arg
```

I am not quite sure how to get the "arguments" to refer to hp, image, speed, x and y ? Or am I stuck with using a list like below ?

```
class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, hp, image, speed, x, y):

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super(Character, self).__init__()

        for arg in [self, hp, image, speed, x, y]:
             self.arg = arg
```

Comment: `for arg in [self, hp, image, speed, x, y]: self.arg = arg` will just leave you with a single attribute `arg` with value of `y` ....

Comment: @Sorade was the answer usefull (if yes, please accept)? Did you solve your issue (Please let other people know how you did it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [keyword arguments (`kwargs`)](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameter) and define a list of attributes your instances require and you therefore expect in your `__init__()`. Then you can loop over them and assign your attributes via [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    ATTRS = ('hp', 'image', 'speed', 'x', 'y')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super(Character, self).__init__()
        for attr in self.ATTRS:
            setattr(self, attr, kwargs.get(attr))  # sets to None if missing
        set_rect(...)  # do your processing of x, y
```

Or, even simpler, just turning all `kwargs` into instance attributes:

```
class Character(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Character, self).__init__()
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

I would, however, advise you against such trickery. It might make your `__init__` shorter, but it will hurt your productivity later, as most IDE's (Eclipse-PyDev, PyCharm, etc.) code completion/resolution features will not detect such dynamically set attributes on existing instances and also not suggest the required arguments when calling the constructor, which is especially annoying for other coders using your class.

It also does not make your code more readable. Imagine inheriting a code base that uses lots of such constructions. You will learn to like a clean explicit version like the first one you are suggesting in your question. A compromise to shorten your constructor would be using [multiple assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182573/multiple-assignment-semantics)

```
self.image, self.speed, self.hp = image, speed, hp
self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(x, y)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a argument list, but I'm not sure if this is what you want...

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            print(arg)

t = Test("one", 2, "three")
```

Comment: But you can't assign them to your instance fields this way.

Comment: You are right. The answer from @schwobaseggl addresses this issue ;)